# Simple keypress event not working correctly on jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, input, keypress

My code works but only returns true if I write again after the string that exists. where `flowName` is a text `input`.

For example: Database: Flow123

on keypress: Flow123 returns false but when i click in another key it returns true.

This is my code:

```
//validate flow name
$('#flowName').keypress(function () {
   var flowName = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
       url: '/check-flowName',
       type: 'post',
       data: {flowName: flowName},
       success: function (result) {
           console.log(result);
           //if exists
           if (result) {

           }
           //else do nothing
       }
   })
});
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You may use `keydown`

Comment: or `".on("input"...` which will handle paste too

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i got the same. only returns true after i press another key

Comment: try to use `.bind("change",function(){your ajax call})`

Comment: Regardless of the return value, is the AJAX call fired and does it send the correct inputs?

Comment: what's there in `result`?

Comment: @RayLloy `change` is the least useful event here

Comment: Yes. I did `console.log(flowName);` and everytime i write it's missing 1 char

Comment: For example: when there's Flow on the input the console log shows Flo

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think so. `change` is better because the event is fired when the value has changed.

Comment: _When the element loses focus after its value was changed, but not commited (e.g. after editing the value of <textarea> or <input type="text">)._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `keypress` you will loose the last pressed `key` in the value of your `input`, **because the `event` is fired when the key is pressed**, so it doesn't take this key into consideration in the `input` value.

**Solution:**

You will need to use **[`keyup` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keyup)**, so the last pressed key can be considered into the `value` when the key is released.

Just replace the `keypress` with `keyup` in your code:

```
$('#flowName').keyup(function () {
   var flowName = $(this).val();

});
```